# phonegap with xcode 4 won't run on ios 3.1.3 (UIKIT)

Tags: ios, uikit

When running a simple HelloWorld phonegap project , 
on iPhone 4 with 4.3.2 OS it works great

But when I tried to run it on iPhone 3 with 3.1.3 OS I have came across with a problem with the CoreMedia lib which i needed to 'weak' in the build settings.

Once I worked this one out, I came across with a whole new problem which I couldn't find a solution for:

dyld: Symbol not found: _UIAccessbilityAnnouncmentNotifcation 
.... Excpeted in /SystemLibrary/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKIT

Both Project and Target Deployment Target is 3.1

Any idea's? 
Thanks in advance 
Guy.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for necromancing, i'm just answering if you still have this problem or someone else encounters it. The following solution may help:

```
This is covered in the README FAQ. Basically you need to weak link three frameworks for iOS 3.x:
1. CoreMedia
2. AVFoundation
3. UIKit

Try that and see if that solves your problem.
```

Source:
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/ios_3_1_3_crashing_when_using_phonegap_with_xcode_4_uikit_problem?from_gsfn=true

Hope this helps!